# How to display pictures of my Facebook friends in a calendar

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm developing a Facebook app in which I want to display the picture of my friend against his birth date. For example, today is April 26; if any of my friend's birthdays are today, his/her picture should display in the calendar slot for the 26th, etc.

Here's my query so far:

```
$dt = "April 12";

$fql1 = "SELECT uid,pic_big,pic,pic_small,name 
    FROM user 
    WHERE birthday='".$dt."' AND 
        uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1= $user)";
```

I want to be able to handle both full dates (i.e. April 12, 1986) and partial dates (April 12).

This is my Calender code

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="400"  align="center" style="border:1px solid #cccccc;">
    <tr><td colspan="3" align="center" class="viewlink"><?php echo $msg;?></td></tr>
    <tr >

    <td width="120" colspan="1" >
        <input type="button" value=" < " onClick="goLastMonth(<?php echo $month . ", " . $year; ?>);">
    </td>
    <td colspan="5" width="610" align="center">
        <span class="title"><?php echo $monthName . " " . $year; ?></span><br>
    </td>
    <td width="120" colspan="1" align="right" style="padding-right:2px;">
        <input type="button" value=" > " onClick="goNextMonth(<?php echo $month . ", " . $year; ?>);">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Sunday</td>
    <th width="45">Mondy</th>
    <th width="89">Tuesday</th>
    <th width="126">Wednesday</th>
    <th width="98">Thursday</th>
    <th width="69">Friday</th>
    <th>Saturday</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<?php
    for($i = 1; $i < $numDays+1; $i++, $counter++){
        $dateToCompare = $month . '-' . $i . '-' . $year;
        $timeStamp = strtotime("$year-$month-$i");
        //echo $timeStamp . '<br/>';
        if($i == 1){
            // Workout when the first day of the month is
            $firstDay = date("w", $timeStamp);
            for($j = 0; $j < $firstDay; $j++, $counter++){
                echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }
        if($counter % 7 == 0){
            ?>
            </tr><tr>
            <?php
        }

        $pdate=strlen($i);
        if($pdate==1)
        {
            $day="0".$i;
        }
        else
        {
            $day=$i;
        }

        $pmonth=strlen($month);
        if($pmonth==1)
        {
            $mon="0".$month;
        }
        else
        {
            $mon=$month;
        }

    ?>

    <!--right here--><td width="323" <?=hiLightEvt($month,$i,$year);?> valign="top" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#960; text-align:center; padding:10px; margin:0; border:1px dotted #cccccc;" class="viewlink" ><?=$i;?><br />

    <?php
        **/////////////////////////////Here I want to display friends picture whose birthday at relevant date//////////////////////**
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you try to format your code, SO's editor seems to be a little nuts lately, but i can't really see what your code is doing because it's not formatted and characters are missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little hard to understand; but from what I do understand - you're having a problem finding your friends' birthdays for a specific date.

I would suggest going about this problem in a different way.  It looks like you're doing a single FQL query for each date in your calendar.  I think it'd be better to load all of a users' friends, and loop through each of them and extrapolate the date.  According to [Facebook's documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/), the birthday date format is relative to the users' locale, so you are not going to be able to reliably query against that field.

An alternative: (***edited** to be more complete. almost completely copy and pasteable now.*)

```
<?php

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => FB_APP_ID, //put your FB APP ID here
    'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET, //put your FB APP SECRET KEY here
    'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

if ($session)
{
    //check to see if we have friends_birthday permission
    $perms = $facebook->api('/me/permissions');
}

 //we do this to see if the user is logged & installed
if (empty($session) || empty($perms['friends_birthday']))
{
    //get url to oauth endpoint for install/login
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        //put the URL to this page, relative to the FB canvas
        //(apps.facebook.com) here vvv
        'next' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/path_to_your_app/index.php',
        'req_perms' => 'friends_birthday'
    ));

    //use javascript to redirect. the oauth endpoint cant be loaded in an
    //iframe, so we have to bust out of the iframe and load it in the browser
    //and tell the oauth endpoint to come back to the fb canvas location
    echo "<script>window.top.location='{$loginUrl}';</script>";
    exit;
}

$user = $session['uid']; //load the user id from the session array

$cur_month_birthdays = array();
$cur_month = 4; //april

try {

    $fql1 = "SELECT uid, pic_big, pic,pic_small, name, birthday FROM user "
    .   "WHERE uid IN ( "
    .       "SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = {$user} "
    .   ")";

    $friends = $facebook->api(array(
        'method'    => 'fql.query',
        'query'     => $fql1
    ));

    //make sure i have some friends...
    if (!empty($friends)) 
    {
        foreach ($friends as $friend)
        {
            //if this friend doesn't have their bday specified, skip them.
            if (empty($friend['birthday']))
            { 
                continue;
            }

            //get unix time for the users' birthday
            $birthday_ts = strtotime($friend['birthday']);

            //if this friends birthday is this month...
            if (date('m', $birthday_ts) == $cur_month)
            {
                //generate a month-day string for the birthdate
                $birthday_str = date('m-d', $birthday_ts);

                //initialize the array of friends with birthdays on this date
                if (empty($cur_month_birthdays[ $birthday_str ]))
                {
                    $cur_month_birthdays[ $birthday_str ] = array();
                }

                $cur_month_birthdays[ $birthday_str ] []= $friend;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    //error with facebook
    error_log($e);
}

//output list of days in this month with friends that have birthdays
print_r($cur_month_birthdays);
```

The above code will fetch all your users' friends, loop through each, and find the ones with a birthday that is in your current month (defined as `$cur_month`).  You can then loop through and build your calendar, and for each day you check the `$cur_month_birthdays` array to see if there are any friends that have a birthday on the current day, and display them appropriately.

Hope that helps!

** **edit** **

This is my output for the above script.  I have edited it to be more thorough it's set-up (including initialization of the FB PHP SDK and fetching of the users' session.  I had assumed that you had at *least* that code in place.  Now that you can see the structure of the array - you should be able to easily figure out how to integrate into your calendar.

```
Array
(
    [04-04] => Array
    (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 123123
                [pic_big] => url-to-pic
                [pic] => url-to-pic
                [pic_small] => url-to-pic
                [name] => Thomas W
                [birthday] => April 4, 1985
            )

    )

    [04-19] => Array
    (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 123123
                [pic_big] => url-to-pic
                [pic] => url-to-pic
                [pic_small] => url-to-pic
                [name] => Joel S
                [birthday] => April 19
            )

    )

    [04-29] => Array
    (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 123123
                [pic_big] => url-to-pic
                [pic] => url-to-pic
                [pic_small] => url-to-pic
                [name] => Ashley F
                [birthday] => April 29, 1983
            )

            [1] => Array
            (
                [uid] => 123123
                [pic_big] => url-to-pic
                [pic] => url-to-pic
                [pic_small] => url-to-pic
                [name] => Megan S
                [birthday] => April 29, 1989
            )

    )
)
```

Comment: Thank Jim for response.I embed this code this display only Array().Nothing else. Can you please that how i can embed it in my calender. thanks

Comment: I apologize, there is an error in my code - let me fix it for you real quick.  It's on line 36, instead of $friend['birthday'] you  need to use $birthday_ts. editing now.

Comment: As to showing you how to embed it into your calendar, I don't know the details of your calendar generation script so I can't really do that very well.  But, the $cur_month_birthdays array is indexed on date of the month (M-DD) so you just check each day-key for the people who have birthdays on that date.  A non existent key means no birthdays on that day, but if there ARE birthdays, then each user with a birthday on thate date will be an element in the array

Comment: Thanks Jim that you are doing effort for me but dear there is same result. I mean it echo Array() only nothing else.
Actually following is my Calender Code I write comments of Dates area where friends picture will be display whose birthday of that date.
I put code in my previous Post. I mean now my question is updated>

Comment: @Mohammad Shafiq, I edited my answer to show example output and added more code to make it almost 100% copy and paste-able to get the exact output I have.  All you have to do is put your application information in.

Comment: Thanks JimR
Me facing same problem
my apps is http://apps.facebook.com/wish_mirrors/index.php?m-fbbirthday

Comment: Thanks JimR
Me facing same problem
my apps is http://apps.facebook.com/wish_mirrors/index.php?m-fbbirthday
you can download my file from this link
https://www.mentorlogix.com/demo/wish_mirrors/birhtday.zip

Comment: @Mohammad Shafiq - alright man, I went through your code and got it to a working state.  I tried not to change too terribly much, so you could recognize the code. You can get it here: http://pastie.org/private/pt0qy1krpl4n06zhj1kw What you were doing wrong is you didn't notice that your birthday pictures got pulled all at once.  This part of the script belongs at the top of the page (i put it in a function). Then on line 304 i called the function to get the pictures, then on line 383 you'll see where i implemented the check/display of the pictures.  I hope you can go off of this. Good luck!

Comment: Also, here's a screen shot of it working: http://o7.no/91596/7mc2.png and..as a side-note. Please regenerate your application secret.  You really don't want that posted on the internet like that, as it compromises the integrity of your application (other people can start using your app as you, from their servers). And take care to not post that information in the future (: Good luck, again.

Comment: @JimR Thanks a Lot Mr Jim . I appreciate your efforts for me. I run this script.Its shows result for me only in 12th month only one picture. Although I have a lot of friends whose has birth day in May.
And our script only shows One and that for December.
Can you mention it please with thanks>

Comment: @ I think Mr Jim so many users haven't birthday in this form like "May-12-1988" etc I think mostly have like this 12/12/1988, 05/05/1976.
that you say about it. I think we should got a solution for second option.
Best Regard
Mohammad Shafiq

Comment: @Mohammad - `strtotime()` should take care of a lot of the formats that people can use for their birthday.  However, you might have to help it along by doing some string processing.  You are clearly not from the USA so you (and your friends) most likely format your dates differently (Instead of MM-DD-YYYY you might use DD-MM-YYYY) and because of that, `strtotime()` might get confused. You might try to read more about PHP's [DateTime](http://us2.php.net/datetime) library. It will almost certainly help you parse dates for your Country/Locale.

Comment: Hello Jim Rubenstein your code is accurate correct. Actually I detected my all friends birthday and birthday_date but unfortunately all friends have empty these both fields.
Only one friend have data in both fields and he is displaying in my calender.
But the thing is that I used any other application which is displaying my so many friends birthday.
So what is happening is there any other field for birthday in face book db .

If not then why fb query detecting these fields empty in database. can you help please. I appreciate your efforts for me and you done job with excellently.
Any Idea ?

Comment: @Mohammad- Actually, I'll bet I know what the problem is! You need to request the `friends_birthday` extended permission!  You don't get access to friends' birthdays without that permission!  I've updated my code to show you how to request it!

Comment: @Jim Rubenstein How are you. Thanks a lot dear my problem has been solved due to your efforts. Thank you so much.Now all friends pictures are displaying in calender.
thanks again

Comment: fantastic, accept the answer and lets move on! haha. I hope you learned a bit from this topic (: